# Drawing Circles on random JPanels by Pressing a JButton

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I got a grid with JPanels, by pressing the Button on top I want a random generator to draw circles on 3 random Panels. 
In theory I think I have to overwrite the PaintComponent of every JPanel with a circle, put the flag on false and when I press the button an action listener puts the flag of 3 random JPanels on true.

But I really have no idea how to do this. Is it possible to do it this way ? if yes, could you show me how, if no, could you tell me what else i have to do ? Thanks a lot. Here's my code so far:

```
package feld;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Spielplan {

public static void main(String[] args) {



JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
f1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

JButton tokens = new JButton("Spielsteine setzen");
f1.add(tokens, BorderLayout.NORTH);

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
f1.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel g1 = new JPanel();
g1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g1.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g1);


JPanel g2 = new JPanel();
g2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g2.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g2);

JPanel g3 = new JPanel();
g3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g3.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g3);

JPanel g4 = new JPanel();
g4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g4.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g4);

JPanel g5 = new JPanel();
g5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g5.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g5);

JPanel g6 = new JPanel();
g6.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g6.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g6);

JPanel g7 = new JPanel();
g7.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g7.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g7);

JPanel g8 = new JPanel();
g8.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g8.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g8);

JPanel g9 = new JPanel();
g9.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
g9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g9.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g9);

f1.pack();
f1.setVisible(true);    




}
}
```

Comment: You need to store these boolean flags somewhere -- the easiest is to declare a subclass of `JPanel` which has said flag and use that instead of `JPanel` when you instantiate `g1`...`g9`.

Comment: Just a general suggestion. You don't have to set preferred size if you are adding the component to `GridLayout` (which is then added to `BorderLayout`). It will be ignored. Also, you can create your panels in for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I could think of is to create s subclass of `JPanel` with a boolean to determine whether the circle should be drawn. I named it `CirclePanel`:

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel{

    public static final Color circleColor = Color.BLACK;

    private boolean drawCircle;

    public CirclePanel() {
        drawCircle=false;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void setDrawCircle(boolean drawCircle) {
        this.drawCircle = drawCircle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(drawCircle) {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Color tmp = g2d.getColor();
            g2d.setColor(circleColor);

            g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g2d.setColor(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a subclass of `JFrame` for the frame but you could also do it in a `main` method. I placed the circle panels in an array to avoid repeating code and placed them in a grid. When the button is clicked, a `List` of indices are created and three are removed at random. The list is then used to set the boolean variable of the panels. see below:

```
public class CircleGrid extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private CirclePanel[] panels;
    private JButton button;


    public CircleGrid() {
        super("Circle test");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panels = new CirclePanel[9];
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            panels[i] = new CirclePanel();
            center.add(panels[i]);
        }

        button = new JButton("Color in");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(button)) {
            // select three random circle indices -
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353488/7015661
            ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int numRandom = 3; // three indices

            for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                indices.add(i);
            }

            Random r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < numRandom; i++) {
                int rndPos1 = r.nextInt(indices.size());
                indices.remove(rndPos1); // remove three indices from the list
            }

            // change panel boolean
            for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
                CirclePanel pi = panels[i];

                if(indices.contains(i)) {
                    // no circle
                    pi.setDrawCircle(false);
                }else {
                    //draw circle
                    pi.setDrawCircle(true);
                }
            }

            repaint(); // redraw panels
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CircleGrid();
    }
}
```

I end up with the following:

[image: Test UI]

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Otherwise, nice example. Plus one.

Comment: Thank you :) Agreed, it looks sloppy if there's too much white space.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. But when i try to test your code in my Eclipse I always get this error: 
Illegal modifier for the local class CirclePanel; only abstract or final is permittedIllegal modifier for the local class CircleGrid; only abstract or final is permitted

Comment: @vesety did you put each class in a separate .java file?

Comment: okay no i didn't sorry its my first weak coding so i havnt know this. now it works i hope i can understand it a bit better now. Thanks a lot and great work

Comment: My pleasure, the only tricky bit occurs when the button is clicked. Do ask if there's something you do not understand.

Comment: Right now I dont understand much of it but I think I should just start with "easier" projects, maybe this is a bit to hard for me right now. 
Any suggestions what i could do for the beginning to understand more ?

Comment: I think starting with examples are a good option. You can have a look at Derek Banas on YouTube. He's got some great tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is essentially before your draw on your jPanel white out the entire panel then draw your circle apply the code below hopes in helps.

```
int name=(int) Math.random() * 100;
int name1=(int) Math.random() * 100;
```

Then you would draw the circle on the JPanels using the graphics method and the appropriate code. Below is the code that draws the circle in a random place:

```
g.draw/fillOval (name,name1,100,100);
```

Comment: sorry im prettay new in coding and i don't really know how to use this

Comment: public void paint (Graphics g) {
 } //Call the graphics method via Graphics g = g.getGraphics(); in your other methods